# Unable to enter the if statement | Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fade two images back and forth:

- Image1 with an id of `imageone`
- Image2 with an id of `imagetwo`

For both the images, I have linked `onClick` in UI properties to the `onClick` method in the below Java code.

After the launching the app, when I click on `image1`, it is supposed to fade *out* and `image2` should fade IN.

After analysis, I determined that the flow is not entering the `if` statement and is always getting directed to `else` no matter what.

How can I solve this?

Why is the `if` statement `if (view.getId() == R.id.imageone)` not letting the flow inside it even though the entry condition `view.getId() == R.id.imageone` is true?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView imageone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageone);

        ImageView imagetwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagetwo);

        if (view.getId() == R.id.imageone) {
            imageone.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);//image1 fade OUT

            imagetwo.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);//image2 fade IN
        } else {
            imagetwo.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);//image2 fade OUT

            imageone.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);//image1 fade IN
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried String.equals() instead of ==?

Comment: Better if you post the layout as well. Cause could be because your imagetwo is on top of imageone and is only visible and clickable.

Comment: @TimStraubinger [`view.getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) returns an int. `==` is fine.

Comment: @Narendra Jadon : You are right ,The problem was with the layout. The image two was on top of image one. And i solved it by setting the image one on top of image 2. Thank you everyone  for your help.

Comment: @NarendraJadon join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Answer (score 0):

@Narendra Jadon : You are right ,The problem was with the layout. The image two was on top of image one. And i solved it by setting the image one on top of image 2. Thank you everyone for your help.